# How to create a reusable provider in Angular 4

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to replace this provider code with an object that can be imported into components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: './my-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-selector.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SomeSelectorComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

So, this section:

```
{
   provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
   useExisting: forwardRef(() => SomeSelectorComponent),
   multi: true
}
```

Would be moved into some kind of class or something and imported into the component like:

```
import { myCustomProvider } from './core'
```

Is that possible in Angular2/4?

Comment: its just a json object, you can make a get call to get it and place it there, not sure it will although

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Could you show an example of that?